# How to creat a cursor for a figure/window of matplotlib with python shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, matplotlib

Basically I am working on data treatment. I created my class in order to read some `csv` files and to manipulate them. My goal is to create a method which is aimed at plotting its parameters against time all in the same figure in one column. I have created a script for that and I have to import it in python shell (for my job) and to call the function.

But the issue is I can not find a good way to do it. Currently I cannot see all the graphics. In this situation liste_data has just 6 columns, in real situation the number of columns might be bigger than 6. The function has to be convenient and usable for close to 100 parameters and the axis has to be readable.

I am currently looking for code that can create a single cursor on the figure (on the window) to access all the graphs.

```
class LxAy

    #- liste_data->np.array[line,column] 
    #each column represente one type of data
    # the first column is time


def time_graph(self): 

      #it is not interesting to plot time against time. 
      #if len(liste_data[0,:]==x so we have x-1 graphs

        nb_graphs=len(self.liste_data[0,:])-1
        plt.subplots(nb_graphs,1))
        fig,stockage=plt.subplots(nb_graphs,1)
        plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left= 0.1, bottom = 0.1, right = 0.9 , top = 2, wspace=0, hspace = 0.7) # this is not final parameters
        i=1
        for axis in stockage[1:]:
            axis.plot(self.liste_data[:,0],self.liste_data[:,i])
            axis.set_title("blabla :"+str (i))
            i+=1
        plt.show()
```

- When I ran it in [spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qc0w.png).
- When I ran it in [python shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WmRs.png) after importing my script.

EDIT :

As we can see in the Ipython console in spyder. I can go up or down if I want to look the first or the last graph (blabla1 or blabla 5).
[We can see cursor on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxx4L.png)

But when I am importing the script from Python shell, I can not see all the graphs. For example, looking blabla1 and blabla5. And I am wondering if there is one way to create a figure (window ?) with a cursor in order to do that. Currently I can only see 3 out of 5 graphs whereas in this situation it is just a small number (6 columns in liste_data).

Answer (score 0):

to be honest I'm not 100% clear on what your actual question is..but if you want to add a cursor to your plot as the original question suggests, refer to the matplotlib documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/widgets/cursor.html

using your notation...

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
cursor = Cursor(axis, useblit=True, color='red', linewidth=2)
```

Comment: First, I thank you for your help.
Let me rephrase it.